# Expressing Representation of a Colimit as a Limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, representable-functor

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}_\C}
\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}
\newcommand{\colim}{\mathrm{colim}}$

Let $\C$ be a locally small category and $(\I,X)$ be a diagram in $\C$. That is, $\I$ is a small category and $X$ is a  covariant functor. I know from textbook, that if colimit of the diagram exists, then there is a natural isomorphism

$$ \lim_{i \in \I^\op} \Hom(X_i,\cdot) \iff \Hom(\colim_{i \in \I} X_i,\cdot) $$

Which can be indurstood as representation of compound contravariant functor by the colimit existing in $\C$.

I wonder that if limit of $(\I,X)$ exists in $\C$, then this result must dualize to

$$  \colim_{i \in \I^\op} \Hom(X_i,\cdot) \iff \Hom(\lim_{i \in \I} X_i,\cdot), $$

And I decided to prove this result myself, but I have some problems. Now I think that this  is not a correct dualizartion of the firs statement, but I still want prove it, as colimits still might have some representation.

> Is the second statement correct? How to prove it?

My work so far:

Denote by $(L,\lambda)$ limit of $(\I,X)$ in $\C$.

Let $A$ to be any object in $\C$. Then colimit $(\L^A,\Lambda^A)$ of diagram $(\I,\Hom(X,A))$ exists in the category $\mathsf{SET}$ as $\mathsf{SET}$ is  cocomplete.

In order to prove natuaral correspondence I need to construct a bijection $\alpha_A$ between $\L^A$ and $\Hom(L,A)$ and then prove that it's natural.
Using pullbacks $\lambda_* : f \mapsto f \circ \lambda$ as legs of $\Hom(L,A)$ defines a cocone over $(\I,\Hom(X,A))$. And by properties of colimits there is a unique map $\alpha_A : \L^A \to \Hom(L,A) $ with $\Lambda^A \alpha_A = \lambda_*$.

Now I need to find an Inverse of $\alpha_A$ and I stacked here. And I know additionally that $\Lambda^A$ is surjective and that 
$$\L^A \cong \frac{\coprod_{i \in \I} \Hom(X_i,A) }{(\sim)}. $$

But this seems to produce the map of the same direction.

p.s.

I defined some mathjax commands \C,\I,\L,\Hom, \op,\colim to speed-up typesetting. I think, you can use them in answers and comments

Comment: No, this statement is very false; you haven't dualized correctly. The correct dualization is just that Homs into a limit are computed by a limit.

Comment: This is not the right dual statement. Note that the duality happens in $C$, not in $Set$. The dual statement is $Lim Hom(-, X_i) = Hom(-, Lim X_i)$

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I rhought, but are there any similar statement which has colimit outside of Hom?

Comment: The main example I can think of with colimits outside is when $S$ is a [small object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+object) or a [tiny object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) in which case you'd have $$ \colim \hom(S, X_i) \cong \hom(S, \colim X_i) $$ for colimits of suitable shape.

Comment: @Hurkyl  So I see, that this property is rather special and there are no general theorems of this sort.